# How to install libc6 2.14 exactly?

Tags: linux

I need to install this version to avoid this error:

```
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/vmagent/app/lib/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so)
```

I tried to run command:

```
konstantin@gae-default-1-yqpu:/home/vmagent$ sudo apt-get install libc6=2.14
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.14' for 'libc6' was not found
```

but you see how it ends. What I need to do next?

Comment: What do you get from `nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC`?

Comment: @grawity
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.10
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.11
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.12
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.13
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.2.6
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.3
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.3.2
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.3.3
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.3.4
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.4
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.5
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.6
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.7
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.8
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.9
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_PRIVATE

Comment: I'd highly recommend that you do not try installing another version of `libc` on your machine.  Unless you really know what you're doing, that's a great way to wind up having to reinstall your entire system.  You likely have a dependency issue, where the library you're trying to use was built on a different system.  Fix *that*.  Don't replace `libc` on a different system.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - I am not linux user from birth and don't know much about it. All I need is to make that lib load somehow. I use Google App Engine VMs to run thins thing, so I don't care what will happen with it. Anyway each project update google creates new VM from scratch. The lib I trying to use is: `https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html`

Comment: @Kosmos: Oooookay, in that case, what libc package version do you have?

Comment: @grawity - Ugh, how I can know that? I use linux for a week.

Comment: @Kosmos: I know you're not a [SE] user from birth, but very few of us are. Please stop posting supplementary information about your situation as comments — you should [edit] your question, and put the information there.